# Azure policy fails to deploy a policy assignment with deployIfNotExists

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-policy

I have a resource whitelist policy defined as follows:

```json
{
  "properties": {
    "displayName": "Deny resource creation if not in whitelist",
    "policyType": "Custom",
    "mode": "Indexed",
    "description": "This policy denies the creation resources which are not allowed in the whitelist.",
    "policyRule": {
      "if": {
        "not": {
          "field": "type",
          "in": [
            "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults",
            "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts"
          ]
        }
      },
      "then": {
        "effect": "Deny"
      }
    }
  },
  "id": "<POLICYDEFINITIONID>",
  "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions",
  "name": "Deny_resource_creation_if_not_in_whitelist",
}
```

This policy works as expected when assigned to a resource group.

I also have a second policy assigned at the subscription level to deploy the first policy on resource groups with names starting with "rg-*":

```json
{
  "properties": {
    "displayName": "Deploy resource whitelist policy",
    "policyType": "Custom",
    "mode": "All",
    "description": "This policy assigns the resource whitelist policy to resource groups starting with rg-*.",
    "policyRule": {
      "if": {
        "allOf": [
          {
            "equals": "Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourceGroups",
            "field": "type"
          },
          {
            "field": "name",
            "like": "rg-*"
          }
        ]
      },
      "then": {
        "details": {
          "deployment": {
            "properties": {
              "mode": "incremental",
              "template": {
                "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
                "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
                "resources": [
                  {
                    "apiVersion": "2022-06-01",
                    "name": "[guid('<POLICYDEFINITIONID>', resourceGroup().name)]",
                    "properties": {
                      "displayName": "Deny resource creation if not in whitelist",
                      "enforcementMode": "Default",
                      "policyDefinitionId": "<POLICYDEFINITIONID>"
                    },
                    "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/policyAssignments"
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          "evaluationDelay": "AfterProvisioning",
          "roleDefinitionIds": [
            "/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/8e3af657-a8ff-443c-a75c-2fe8c4bcb635"
          ],
          "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/policyAssignments"
        },
        "effect": "DeployIfNotExists"
      }
    }
  },
  "id": "",
  "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions",
  "name": "Deploy_resource_whitelist_policy",
}
```

The second policy is evaluated, I can see a successful deployIfNotExists event but in fact the assignment is not created.

A few additional facts:

- I successfully deployed the policy assignment ARM template from the Azure portal
- When replacing the policy assignment ARM template with a simple storage account ARM template it works, a storage account is created in the resource group.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved this using only the first policy and a [value expression condition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/concepts/definition-structure#value):

```json
{
  "properties": {
    "displayName": "Deny resource creation if not in whitelist",
    "policyType": "Custom",
    "mode": "Indexed",
    "description": "This policy denies the creation resources which are not allowed in the whitelist.",
    "policyRule": {
      "if": {
        "allOf": [
          {
            "field": "type",
            "notIn": [
              "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults",
              "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts"
            ]
          },
          {
            "value": "[resourceGroup().name]",
            "like": "rg-*"
          }
        ]
      },
      "then": {
        "effect": "Deny"
      }
    }
  },
  "id": "<POLICYDEFINITIONID>",
  "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions",
  "name": "Deny_resource_creation_if_not_in_whitelist",
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your policy assignment in the example seems to be missing a `scope` property to assign it to the given resourcegroup. Try adding a *scope* property to the policy assignment.

````
"template": {
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "resources": [
    {
        "apiVersion": "2022-06-01",
        "name": "[guid('<POLICYDEFINITIONID>', resourceGroup().name)]",
        "properties": {
            "displayName": "Deny resource creation if not in whitelist",
            "enforcementMode": "Default",
            "policyDefinitionId": "<POLICYDEFINITIONID>"
            "scope": "[subscriptionResourceId('Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups', resourceGroup().name)]"
    },
    "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/policyAssignments"
}```
````

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This does not work, I previously tested it and re-tested it just now. In the [Microsoft documentation for version 2022-06-01 of the API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.authorization/policyassignments?pivots=deployment-language-arm-template) the scope is not mandatory, by default it takes the deployment scope which is the resource group.